# Query performance issue when executing from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-performance

I try to execute a query from another database, using both synonyms and a direct call like  `select * from [DB].[schema].[view]` .

When I run the query on the original database it executes in 1 second. If I call the view from another database, no matter if I use synonyms or a call like "[DB].[schema].[view]" it take about 1.5 MINUTES to execute.
Any idea what the problem might be?

```
USE DB
GO;
select * from schema.view //working fine : 1 second
GO;

use master
GO;
select * from db.schema.view //taking more than 1.5 minutes   
GO;
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense if the databases are on the same server.  To be honest, it wouldn't really make sense on different servers either.  One thing would be to look at the execution plan.  Perhaps it changes for some reason between the two runs.

Comment: It seems it's a compatibility level issue. When I changed the compatibility level to 100 (as same as the original database) everything works fine.

Comment: . . That is quite interesting.  I forget that compatibility can affect things that are not directly seen (like the optimizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a compatibility level problem. Thanks to this  post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194612/poor-performance-when-calling-query-from-another-db-on-same-server.

Curios it's that if compatibility level is 140 I have bad performance, but if I change the compatibility level to 100 everything works fine

Comment: If you would post the text of the view, the query plans, or stats profile output there may be something simpler than the hammer of changing the whole compat level to fix this query to be fast for you.  Sometimes it's something small (rebuild your index or stats) that allows you to get the other performance enhancements that exist in 140+ for the rest of your app.  I suggest you not stop at "lower compat is faster so I am done" - this is usually not the whole story

Comment: This implies you put `master` into compatibility 100 on a SQL Server 2017 instance! That is very likely an *awful* idea.

Comment: Probably :D but it's not the case. Master was an example, it's not the database in case. As suggested @ConorCunninghamMSFT, I will try to look into stats profile

Comment: I published the query and stats profile [here](https://pastebin.com/efp8Amf5). I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you